django unresolved tag "load" at DRF api.html
I have the following fully-functioning project/rest_framework/api.html:
{% extends 'rest_framework/base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block style %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/General.css' %}">
{% endblock %}

the problem is, that load is underlined, commented "unresolved tag 'load'. As well no style changes apear on web page even after restarting the server and shift-f5 reload.

This is just the linter that is faulty.

Yes, thanks, I already figured it out
